# Facebook Javascript URI not redirecting to redirect uri when adding page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on an app to add an app to Facebook Pages. The adding part works fine but I am not getting a proper redirect from Facebook, so I am unable to link the user to the facebook page. Here is my Javascript code:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'pagetab',
   redirect_uri: 'http://mycallback.url'
}
```

I am getting a response and the page is being added, but nothing is being called on the URI specified by the redirect uri

Relatedly, is there a way to delete tabs that were added using the UI without requiring a page access token?

Comment: I meant a redirect on to the redirect URI, there is a function that is getting called, I will rephrase the question

Comment: nevermind, i will answer

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate the redirect URL on your own to redirect users to the installed App:

```
https://www.facebook.com/[page-id]/app/[app-id]/
```

Afaik there is no dialog for deleting a tab, so you do need a Page Token for the API call.